# Fetching and displaying data from core data

Tags: ios, swift3

**Aim :**

To be able to display the days selected and the time picked by the user in the same row of the table view. The time should appear at the top and the days selected should appear at the bottom, both in the same row, just like an alarm clock.

**Work :**

This is the relationship I've got setup : 
[image]

and this is how I save the days that are selected from a UITable and the time from a UIDatepicker when the save button is tapped :

```
@IBAction func saveButnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let context =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext //creates an object of a property in AppDelegate.swift so we can access it

        let bob = Bob(context: context)

        //save the time from UIDatePicker to core data
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        bob.timeToPing = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicked.date)

        // save the days selected to core data
        for weekday in filteredWeekdays
        {
            var day = Days(context: context) //create new Days object
            day.daysSelected = weekday as NSObject? //append selected weekday
            bob.addToTimeAndDaysLink(day) //for every loop add day object to bob object
        }

        //Save the data to core data
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

        //after saving data, show the first view controller
        navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Now that the data is once saved, I get the data :

```
func getData()
{
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    do
    {
        bobs = try context.fetch(Bob.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Fetching failed")
    }

}
```

**Attempt to get the days selected :**

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1439567), the below comments and a formerly deleted answer to this question to do this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let bob = bobs[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = bob.timeToPing?.description

    // retrieve the days that are selected
    var daysArray: [Days] = []
    daysArray = bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects as! [Days]

    for days in daysArray
    {
        print (days.daysSelected?.description)
        cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected! as! String

    }

    return cell
}
```

**EDIT :** 
`print(daysArray)` gives this  :

```
[<Days: 0x6080000a5880> (entity: Days; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://30B28771-0569-41D3-8BFB-D2E07A261BF4/Days/p1> ; data: <fault>)]
```

`print(daysArray[0])` gives this :

```
<Days: 0x6080000a5880> (entity: Days; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://30B28771-0569-41D3-8BFB-D2E07A261BF4/Days/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

**How to save days**

```
let weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
var filteredWeekdays: [String] = []
 @NSManaged public var daysSelectedbyUser: NSSet
```

And then

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        selectedWeekdays()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        selectedWeekdays()
    }

    func selectedWeekdays()
    {
        if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        {
            let rows = selectedRows.filter {$0.section == 0}.map{ $0.row}
            filteredWeekdays = rows.map{ weekdays[$0] }
            print(filteredWeekdays)
        }
    }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What error? And the code your posted doesn't appear in your code. I'd guess replace `salawaat` with `bob`? Where is What's the objects in `bobs`? What's `bobs = try context.fetch(Bob.fetchRequest())`?

Comment: Hi @Larme, I just updated the code. Sorry it was a typo.

Comment: Could you show the value of `bob` and the EXACT error or warning message you get?

Comment: Hi, how do I show you the value of bob ? I've updated the original question to add the exact error. I couldn't paste it here as it was too long for comments lol.

Comment: `bob.timeAndDaysLink` that's a NSSet of `Days` object, not a `NSSet` of String object, that's why you have the cast issue.  `daysArray = bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects.valueFor(key:"daysSelected")` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Larme.


So I changed it to `let daysArray = bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects(value(forKey: "daysSelectedbyUser"))`

and I get compilation error saying Cannot call value of non function type '[Any]'

Tried to follow this but didn't know how to implement : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551360/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-any-firebase-swift3

Comment: Let's try this: `var daysArray = [Days](); daysArray = bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects as! [Days]` (`Days` being the class from your CoreData Model). Then `for days in daysArray {print(days); cell.textLabel?.text = days.value(forKey:"daysSelected") as String}`. Note that according to your CoreDataModel it's `daysSelected` not `daysSelectedbyUser` for the key of `value(forKey:)`.

Comment: Thanks Larme. We are close!

I've aded the above and get a crash here :
`class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { ` of type Thread1 : signal SIGABRT` 

I put in breakpoints and everything is working fine till we get to `print(days)`  which is printing this `<Days: 0x6000000aa080> (entity: Days; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://FA7DF8AD-CE1D-4E70-A144-FAF4A3AA18F2/Days/p1> ; data: {
    daysSelected = "{(\n    Wednesday,\n    Tuesday,\n    Thursday\n)}";
})` 

and then the crashes here:  `cell.textLabel?.text = days.value(forKey: "daySelected") as! String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK based on your latest comment that the crash occur on this line:

`cell.textLabel?.text = days.value(forKey: "daySelected") as! String`

It's clearly pointing to the typo you've made in key name. You have: `daySelected` and should be (based on your core data model) `daysSelected`, but nevertheless it's not very good approach to use values for your core data entity and also force type like that. To make it better I suggest replacing this line with:

`cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected!`

This should be already a `String` since this is a String in `CoreData`. In case it's optional (should be an optional), you shouldn't force it. I will assume that whenever data will be not there you will just display empty cell, so even better it will be:

`cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected ?? ""`

This will produce empty string to text, whenever (for some reason) data will be not there.

**EDIT**

So for additional piece of code you put in your question:

In your CoreData field `daysSelected` is type of `String?`, right?
Then you assign `timeAndDateLink` to `NSSet<String>`, right? But expected value here should be `NSSet<Days>`.

So let's edit your input code a bit ( i will put comment on every line):

```
let bob = Bob(context: context) /* create new Bob object */
for weekday in filteredWeekdays {
    var day = Days(context: context) /* create new Days object */
    day.daysSelected = weekday /* append selected weekday */
    bob.addToTimeAndDaysLink(day) /* for every loop add day object to bob object */
}
```

I hope everything is clear in above example. You may have a problem with a compiler in that case, because if you choose generate class for entities you will endup with two `func` with the same name but different parameter (in Swift this should be two different functions, but Xcode sometimes pointing to the wrong one). If you hit that problem try:

```
let bob = Bob(context: context) /* create new Bob object */
var output: NSMutableSet<Days> = NSMutableSet()
for weekday in filteredWeekdays {
    var day = Days(context: context) /* create new Days object */
    day.daysSelected = weekday /* append selected weekday */
    output.add(day)
}
bob.addToTimeAndDaysLink(output) /* this will assign output set to bob object */
```

You should also rename your `Days` entity to `Day` to avoid future confusion that we have right now, `days` as array will only be in relation from other entities to this not entity itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Kuba.
1. `cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected!` is giving compilation error so I was suggested by Xcode to use this : `cell.textLabel?.text = days.value(forKey: "daysSelected") as! String` . It compiles fine but crashes at this line with error  `Could not cast value of type '__NSSetI' (0x1033748b0) to 'NSString' (0x10255eab8) `

Comment: 2. `cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected!` gives compilation error. So I changed it to `cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected! as! String` which crashes at this line with the error `Could not cast value of type '__NSSetI' (0x1023528b0) to 'NSString' (0x10153cab8)`
3. `daysSelected` is of type Transformable and is not optional ( I need it to be not optional). I changed `daysSelected` to a string and get compilation error `daysSelectedbyUser.daysSelected = NSSet(array: filteredWeekdays)` saying `cannot assign value of type 'NSSet' to type String`

Comment: What is the type of yours 'days' variable? And what's the type you want it to be?

Comment: I believe it is of the same type as `daysArray`. From this code :

`daysArray = bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects as! [Days]

        for days in daysArray
        {
            print (days.daysSelected?.description)
              cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected?.description
        }`

Comment: To be honest, I don't have any preference on what variable is stored as what type. I just want the functionality that the user can add a selection of days of week and time to the UITableView. The next part of the project would be to send the user internal notifications at the selected day and time using this as an example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060373/1886931

Comment: How it's declared? As 'Any' of as 'Days'? It should be declared as 'Days'

Comment: I apologise, I don't quite follow. It is declared in the for loop as per the above code in the original question and in the comment above.

Comment: So days it's actually an array of day so you should iterate this value with a 'for' command. Please edit your original question with folllowing final code, it's extremely hard to read from the the command, but you've surely have data type fault there

Comment: But there is a for loop and that is how I iterate daysArray using days. The original question has the code under the cellForRowAt function.

Comment: Is there anything else you would recommend please ?

Comment: As I said - what type of data is your variable `days`? Below line `        daysArray = bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects as! [Days]` put a `print(daysArray)` and next line below `print(daysArray[0])`. There is a great chance the app will crash on the second line, but please share output for first print (and second if successful) in your original question. I'm almost sure that it will be empty. So the next question if that happen will be how you fillup the data for `bob.timeAndDaysLink`? Also update your original question with answer for that one.

Comment: `days` is the same data type as `daysArray` as it is used in the `for loop`. `daysArray` is defined as  `daysArray= bob.timeAndDaysLink?.allObjects as! [Days]`. I've edited the original question for `print(daysArray)` and `print(daysArray[0]`. Please refer to the code in the original question for how I fillup the data in `bob.timeAndDaysLink` by looking at the code in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. Thank you.

Comment: As you can see in a log, data is fault there, so that causing a crash. How do you populate Core data? There is clearly something wrong with inserting data to your Core Data not the fetching this. Please post code.

Comment: So I have `@NSManaged public var daysSelectedbyUser: NSSet` and then then refer to this solution on how to get `filteredWeekdays`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748667/1886931. Then the saving to Core Data is in `func saveButnTapped` as per the original question.

Comment: Yep, please post how you fillup this NsSet with data

Comment: 1)

`@NSManaged public var daysSelectedbyUser: NSSet` is defined at the class level. 

2)
Then `filteredWeekdays` is populated as per this solution so that we know which days the user has tapped and selected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747818/saving-data-from-table-view/44748667#44748667

3)
Then when the save button is pressed, the `func saveButnTapped` is called. The entire code for this function is in the original question. I've pasted it here for you :https://pastebin.com/xVQQY617

Comment: 4) The `NSSet` is saved like this : `daysSelectedbyUser.daysSelected = NSSet(array: filteredWeekdays)`. Thank you.

Comment: But 'filteredWeekdays' is what? Can you paste this also? It's an array of strings or days objects?

Comment: Thanks for the update. So my `saveButnTapped` function now is like this as per your code https://pastebin.com/7NmVEjpC and this is the `cellForRowAt` function here:  https://pastebin.com/Ar1J4EFL . There is a crash at this line `cell.textLabel?.text = days.daysSelected! as! String` and the error is this `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot one line ` day.daysSelected = weekday /* append selected weekday */` there in a for loop. Checkup updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Kuba. We are getting close! The final output is only showing one day that is selected and not all of them. So for e.g. if I select Mon, Wed and Thurs and 08:45 , only Wed is showing up. Secondly, the time that is selected is not showing up either. The code for  `@IBAction func saveButnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)` is here now https://pastebin.com/xDC0xha8 and for `cellForRowAt` is here https://pastebin.com/38hKNE2D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149080/discussion-between-kuba-and-hasnain).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one uses FetchedResultsController, which is made for fetching NSManagedObjects into tableView, but it doesn't matter I guess...

Problem in this question is that you didn't post here your NSManagedObject class for the variable, so I cannot see which type you set there (Should be Transformable in CoreData model and [String] in NSManagedObject class...)

Ignoring all force unwraps and force casting and that mess (which you should pretty damn well fix as first, then it won't crash at least but just don't display any data...)

Days selected by user is NSSet, which it sure shouldn't be.

Please provide you NSManagedObjectClass in here so I can edit this answer and solve your problem...

Comment: HI Dominik,
Thanks for the reply. in the `Days` entity, I have the `daysSelected` attribute which is of type `Transformable`.I did a find in my code and there is only one line which as `@NSManaged` in it which is this variable    `@NSManaged public var daysSelectedbyUser: NSSet`. 


Please refer to the code in the original question under **How to save days** and then the code for `@IBAction func saveButnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)`. Thank you.